# Python text file to xml

Tags: python, xml, csv, text, converters

I have one question about transforming a text file to XML. I have done nice conversion of text file and it's look like:

```
Program: 5 Start: 2013-09-11 05:30:00 Duration 06:15:00 Title: INFOCANALE
```

And my output in XML will be like

```
<data>
  <eg>
    <program>Program 5</program>
    <start>2013-09-11 05:30:00</start>
    <duration>06:15:00</duration>
    <title>INFOCANALE</title>
  </eg>
</dat‌​a>
```

Can python convert text file to XML?
Can you help me with some advice, or some code.

Comment: My text looks like : Program: 5   
            Start:  2013-09-11 05:30:00 
            Duration   06:15:00 
                  Title: INFOCANALE

Comment: And my output will be like: <data><eg><program>Program 5</program><start>2013-09-11 05:30:00</start><duration>06:15:00</duration><title>INFOCANALE</title></eg></data>

Comment: is your file format fixed or you can change it? at least you could put semicolon after each value so it would be easier to parse

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068536/using-argparse-to-convert-csv-to-xml-in-python

Comment: I can change my text file, and I can rename it to whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I think easiest way would be to change your file into csv file like this:

```
Program,Start,Duration,Title
5,2013-09-11 05:30:00,06:15:00,INFOCANALE
```

And then convert it like:

```
from lxml import etree
import csv

root = etree.Element('data')

rdr = csv.reader(open("your file name here"))
header = rdr.next()
for row in rdr:
    eg = etree.SubElement(root, 'eg')
    for h, v in zip(header, row):
        etree.SubElement(eg, h).text = v

f = open(r"C:\temp\data2.xml", "w")
f.write(etree.tostring(root))
f.close()

# you also can use
# etree.ElementTree(root).write(open(r"C:\temp\data2.xml", "w"))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./epg.py", line 53, in <module>
    etree.SubElement(eg, h).text = v
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2659, in lxml.etree.SubElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:53668)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 204, in lxml.etree._makeSubElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:12230)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1542, in lxml.etree._tagValidOrRaise (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:23956)
ValueError: Invalid tag name u'        Program 10   '

Comment: @car have you converted your file into csv? could you put a few strings as an example?

Comment: No i get errors when i wanna convert it, but I'll try with my code for xml. I think it will work.

Comment: output = open('epg.xml','w')
n = 0
print >> output, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'+'\t'
print >> output, '<data>'

with open('epg_slo_utf_xml.txt','r') as txt:
 for line in txt:
  if re.search('Program', line) !=None:
   
   n = n + 1
   e = '<program name=SLO>'+line+'</program>'
    
         if re.search('Start', line) !=None:
    n = n + 1
    f = '<start>'+line+'</start>'
    
    if re.search('Duration', line) !=None:
     n = n + 1
     g = '<duration>'+line+'</duration>'
       
 
    wo = e + f + g   
    
    print >> output, wo + w

print >> output , '</data>'

Comment: @RomanPekar Will it consider the white spaces also? I'm using python 3.2.