# How to convert a .txt to .xml in python

Tags: python, xml, csv, xml-parsing, text-files

So the current problem I'm facing would be in converting a text file into a xml file.
The text file would be in this format.

```
Serial Number:      Operator ID:  test  Time:  00:03:47 Test Step 2      TP1:  17.25    TP2:  2.46
Serial Number:      Operator ID:  test  Time:  00:03:47 Test Step 2      TP1:  17.25    TP2:  2.46
```

I wanted to convert to convert it into a xml with this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <filedata>
 </serialnumber>
 <operatorid>test</operatorid>
 <time>00:00:42 Test Step 2</time>
 <tp1>17.25</tp1>
 <tp2>2.46</tp2>
 </filedata>
...
</root>
```

I was using a code like this to convert my previous text file to xml...but right now I'm facing problems in splitting the lines.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import fileinput
import os
import itertools as it

root = ET.Element('root')
with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'filedata')
for line in it.groupby(lines):
    line=line[0]
    if not line:
        celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'filedata')
    else:
        tag = line.split(":")
        el=ET.SubElement(celldata,tag[0].replace(" ",""))
        tag=' '.join(tag[1:]).strip()
        if 'File Name' in line:
            tag = line.split("\\")[-1].strip()
        elif 'File Size' in line:
            splist =  filter(None,line.split(" "))
            tag = splist[splist.index('Low:')+1]
            #splist[splist.index('High:')+1]
        el.text = tag
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
formatedXML = minidom.parseString(
                          ET.tostring(
                                      root)).toprettyxml(indent=" ",encoding='utf-8').strip()

with open("test.xml","wb") as f:
    f.write(formatedXML)
```

I saw a similar question in stackoverflow 
" [Python text file to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739501/python-text-file-to-xml) "
but the problem is I couldn't change it into a .csv format as this file is generated by a certain machine.
If anyone know how to solve it, please do help.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _Specifically_, what does "I'm facing problems in splitting the lines" mean? What part of the code? What "problems"? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better method of splitting the lines.

Notice that the `text` variable would technically be your `.txt` file, and that I purposely modified it so that we have a greater context of the output.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

# Text would be our loaded .txt file.
text = """Serial Number:  test    Operator ID:  test1  Time:  00:03:47 Test Step 1      TP1:  17.25    TP2:  2.46
Serial Number:      Operator ID:  test2  Time:  00:03:48 Test Step 2      TP1:  17.24    TP2:  2.47"""

# Headers of the intended break-points in the text files.
headers = ["Serial Number:", "Operator ID:", "Time:", "TP1:", "TP2:"]

information = []

# Split our text by lines.
for line in text.split("\n"):

    # Split our text up so we only have the information per header.
    default_header = headers[0]
    for header in headers[1:]:
        line = line.replace(header, default_header)
    info = [i.strip() for i in line.split(default_header)][1:]

    # Compile our header+information together into OrderedDict's.
    compiled_information = OrderedDict()
    for header, info in zip(headers, info):
        compiled_information[header] = info

    # Append to our overall information list.
    information.append(compiled_information)

# Pretty print the information (not needed, only for better display of data.)
pprint(information)
```

Outputs:

```
[OrderedDict([('Serial Number:', 'test'),
              ('Operator ID:', 'test1'),
              ('Time:', '00:03:47 Test Step 1'),
              ('TP1:', '17.25'),
              ('TP2:', '2.46')]),
 OrderedDict([('Serial Number:', ''),
              ('Operator ID:', 'test2'),
              ('Time:', '00:03:48 Test Step 2'),
              ('TP1:', '17.24'),
              ('TP2:', '2.47')])]
```

This method should generalize better than what you are currently writing, and the idea of the code is something I've had saved from another project. I recommend you going through the code and *understanding* its logic.

From here you should be able to loop through the `information` list and create your custom `.xml` file. I would recommend you checking out [`dicttoxml`](https://pypi.org/project/dicttoxml/) as well, as it might make your life much easier on the final step.

In regards to your code, remember: breaking down fundamental tasks is easier than trying to incorporate them all into one. By trying to create the `xml` file while you split your `txt` file you've created a monster that is hard to tackle when it revolts back with bugs. Instead, take it one step at a time -- create "checkpoints" that you are 100% certain work, and then move on to the next task.