# covering text file into xml in python with only space separator

Tags: python, xml

I have a text file it looks like this:

```
1   The star Antares is in which constellation              Scorpius
2   In Islam what is the third piller of wisdom - there's 5 in total        Charity - 2.5 % of
 income
3   Andrew Patterson wrote which definitive Australian song     Waltzing Matilda
```

I have to put it in xml format to read like this

```
<number> number of question</number>
<question> the question</question>
<answer> the last word in the line </answer>
```

the only thing that I have is space there are 3 spaces between the number and the question and 10 spaces between the question and the answer
can it be done this way?

I know how to start

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('xmlfile.xml', encoding='latin-1') as f:
  tree = ET.parse(f)
  root = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a .txt to .xml in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600631/how-to-convert-a-txt-to-xml-in-python)

Comment: not exxactly . because he has same words repeated every line but I have only spaces and different keys

Comment: What is the separator (in the text file)  between the 3 parts?

Comment: only spaces nothing else

Comment: So what is the logic that should separate the 3 parts? I see : "the only thing that I have is space there are 3 spaces between the number and the question and 10 spaces between the question and the answer "

Comment: is there away to do it in javascript by using.   textPieces = textToParse.split(" ");

Comment: only space it start by the number of the question then ( 3 spaces) then the question itself then ( many spaces) then the answer then a new line

Comment: @balderman for clarifying, he always has 3 items in one line (number, question, answer) so you dont need a seperator between the lines. After a line is split (3 items) you move onto the next line.

Comment: I think it is difficult but maybe there is a way to manipulate

Comment: @DoomraiqRaiq see my code below - I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: can we think in it by conditional if like  if there are more than 2 spaces between words put it in another object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
from typing import NamedTuple

SEP1 = '   '
SEP2 = '          '


def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ET.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="\t")

class QuestionAndAnswer(NamedTuple):
  num: str
  question: str
  answer: str

data = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
  lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
  for line in lines:
    sep1_idx = line.find(SEP1)
    num = line[:sep1_idx]
    sep2_idx = line.find(SEP2)
    question = line[sep1_idx + len(SEP1):sep2_idx]
    answer = line[sep2_idx + len(SEP2):]
    data.append(QuestionAndAnswer(num,question,answer))


root = ET.Element('root')
for entry in data:
  q_and_a = ET.SubElement(root,'q_and_a')
  n = ET.SubElement(q_and_a,'number')
  n.text = entry.num
  q = ET.SubElement(q_and_a,'question')
  q.text = entry.question
  a = ET.SubElement(q_and_a,'answer')
  a.text = entry.answer

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree_str = prettify(root)
with open('output.xml','w') as out:
  out.write(tree_str)
```

input.txt

```
1   The star Antares is in which constellation          Scorpius
2   In Islam what is the third piller of wisdom - there's 5 in total          Charity - 2.5 % of
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <q_and_a>
      <number>1</number>
      <question>The star Antares is in which constellation</question>
      <answer>Scorpius</answer>
   </q_and_a>
   <q_and_a>
      <number>2</number>
      <question>In Islam what is the third piller of wisdom - there's 5 in total</question>
      <answer>Charity - 2.5 % of</answer>
   </q_and_a>
</root>
```

Comment: I will check now

Comment: where I find the output file and what you name it

Comment: try https://repl.it/@avishaybalderman/SardonicStarchyProlog There is no output file. I think you are able to create it yourself using  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713184/python-element-tree-writing-to-new-file as an example

Comment: what is wrong it gives me like this    <root><q_and_a><number>1 In Star Trek Generation who was the chief of security killed off Tasha Ya</number><question>In Star Trek Generation who was the chief of security killed off Tasha Ya</question><answer> Trek Generation who was the chief of security killed off Tasha Yar</answer>

Comment: 1) I dont understand the comment above 2) The code was modified and it writes to an output file. See https://repl.it/@avishaybalderman/SardonicStarchyProlog

Comment: I have modified the code. It creates a "nice" XML file. If my solution works for you - feel free to vote up.

Comment: it gives this error.  File "main.py", line 47
    
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: I really don't know what to say and how to thank you. I thought that this thing can be impossible to be done but you make it possible. 1000X1000 thanks @balderman